# Windows console - BAT compatibility

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg, command-prompt, windows-console

I have a command line statement which works perfectly when manually typing it into the console, however, when I put it in a bat file it doesn't work.

```
for %f in (*.flac) do ffmpeg -i "%f" -acodec alac "%~nf.m4a"
```

Here is the error message when I try running the bat file

```
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~nf.m4a"
```

Is there any way to fix this?
The statement converts flac files to alac files using the program ffmpeg.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When batch files are interpreted %% is replaced with %, so your solution would be to replace %f with %%f

Comment: Thanks for that, I had to replace all the % signs, not just the %f.

Comment: @Michael: No, only the parameters of FOR-LOOPs have to preceded with two percents

Comment: @jeb: Aren't all the %'s in that statement in the for loop?